# Mapping by code in NHibernate does not delete child elements in many to one mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, cascading-deletes

I've got the following two C# classes:

```
public class Pet
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PetOwner
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Pet Pet { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm mapping them by code.

In my PetOwner class I have the following ManyToOne mapping for Pet:

```
    ManyToOne<Pet>("Pet", map =>
         {
             map.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy);
             map.Column("Pet_Id");
             map.Cascade(Cascade.Persist | Cascade.DeleteOrphans); 
             map.Insert(true);
             map.Update(true);
         });
```

Now when I call delete on my PetOwner class as follows, it works and the Pet is also deleted:

```
var owner = session.QueryOver<PetOwner>().Take(1).List().FirstOrDefault();
session.Delete(owner);
```

But the following code does not delete the pet at all (and does not give errors either).

```
session.Query<PetOwner>().Delete();
```

Now this is just in my unit tests, and in real life there will be a where clause and I probably won't delete all items, but why is this delete different from the explicit delete using the actual database entity?

Is there a way to get this to work as I'm expecting?

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between your `QueryOver` and `Query` versions.

The `QueryOver` is deleting just a single instance. To do that, it is first loading the entity in memory - honor first level cache. That is why, your `Cascade` are working correctly.

The `Query` version is deleting all the records and is bulk delete operation. It does not load instances in memory - does not honor first level cache.
The [`Query`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/3873844fb0bafea516b416ee82043b7b5a530865/src/NHibernate/Linq/DmlExtensionMethods.cs#L20) interface example in your question actually work as DML. It does not load entities in memory before operating (UPDATE/DELETE) on them.

> ```
> /// Delete all entities selected by the specified query. The delete operation is performed in the database without reading the entities out of it.
> /// </summary>
> /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of <paramref name="source" />.</typeparam>
> /// <param name="source">The query matching the entities to delete.</param>
> /// <returns>The number of deleted entities.</returns>
> public static int Delete<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
> ```

Replies to your comments:

> I understand that, but does it not figure out it should also go and delete those owned items?

As first level cache is not utilized, there is actually nothing "owned".

> so NHibernate does not automatically run something like "delete from PETS where Id in (select Pet_Id from PetOwners)".

With `Query` API, you are actually doing bulk delete -- it works on DML queries. So; no NHibernate does not generate the SQL you are asking for.

> Or is that the type of information that comes from the level 1 cache?

Not First level cache; but the API you choose. This type of information is defined in mappings. But, how to generate the query also depends on what API you are using. You are using `Query` API here.

> So out of curiosity, even if I used hbm mapping files, i would end up with the same scenario?

HBM or code mapping does not matter. Both are same.

> Is there maybe a way I can at least get the delete to fail if the user does not manually also delete the pets? Using mapping by code that is.

Well... use `QueryOver`; but it does not support bulk operations. Any API that support bulk operations will not generate the query you are expecting. Add necessary constraints on database level; that way, you will get exception thrown.